# Bootstrap grid putting images on top of each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues getting the 3 images to appear next to each other. I'm using ng-repeat with angular to output the first 3 images, but they are on top of each other no matter how I mess with the grid's col-md size. Any suggestions on how to get the images next to each other.

[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>

<head>
    <title>Bicycle App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>

                <div class='col-md-12'>

                    <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <!-- end class not needed -->
                <div class="chooseTitle">
                    Choose Your Bicycle
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <!-- you missed md from offset, end class not needed -->
                <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">

                <div ng-repeat ="product in products | limitTo: -3">
              {{product.manufacturer}}
                <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{product.image}}" ></div>
                </div><!--End controller-->
                </div><!--end col-md-3-->

                </div><!--end row-->
        </div> <!--end container-->







    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bikeimageslider.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('formApp', []);
app.controller('BikeController',['$scope', function($scope){



$scope.products = [
{
manufacturer: "Trek",
image: 'images/bike1.jpg'
}, 
{
manufacturer: "Mongoose",
image: 'images/bike2.jpg'

},
{   

    manufacturer: "Portlandia",
image: 'images/bike3.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Giant",
image: 'images/bike4.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Framed",
image: 'images/bike5.jpg'
},
{
manufacturer: "Windsor",
image: 'images/bike6.jpg'
}
];
/*
$scope.LeftArrowClick =function(selectedIndex){
if (products[selectedIndex] = products[-1]){
products[selectedIndex] = products[6];

}

};
$scope.increment =0;
$scope.RightArrowClick =function(selectedIndex){
$scope.selectedIndex++;
    $scope.selectedObject = $scope.products[selectedIndex];

if ($scope.products === 7){
$scope.products = 0;

}
};
*/

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the repeat on a column that spans 3 blocks. Your images don't fit on that space and that's why they are being stacked up.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">
        <div ng-repeat ="product in products | limitTo: -3">
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                {{product.manufacturer}}
                <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{product.image}}" >
            </div>
        </div><!--End controller-->
    </div><!--end col-md-3-->
</div><!--end row-->
```

With this you are creating 3 columns, one for each image.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. I will be using this as reference for the future

Answer (score 0):

Put this class `img-responsive` from `<div class="col-md-3 img-responsive">` to `<img>` element like this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" ng-src=/>
```

Comment: It's an improvement, but not perfect. They are now directly on top of each with the same image sizes. They still need to be next to each other in same bootstrap row. Why aren't they? They are within the 12 columns? I updated code and pic above to reflect changes.

Comment: It works for me. Check it. Maybe I don't understand your problem. 
https://jsfiddle.net/symbwell/5vbbtgfv/